# How to get the 3 first occurrences of a list of fields in a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with USA States and county populations, which I sorted in descending order in order to get the 3 most populous counties in each state but I don´t know the sintax to slice the 3 first occurrences of each state.

I tried

```
census_df=census_df[["STNAME",'CENSUS2010POP']][:3]
```

but got only of the first state (Wyoming). I don´t know if I have to have Multiindex or something like to do this.

A sample of the data follows:

```
        STNAME  CENSUS2010POP
3169    Wyoming 563626
3180    Wyoming 91738
3182    Wyoming 75450
3172    Wyoming 46133
3188    Wyoming 43806
...
3096    Wisconsin   5686986
3137    Wisconsin   947735
3109    Wisconsin   488073
3164    Wisconsin   389891
...
47  Alabama 30776
3   Alabama 27457
31  Alabama 26790
10  Alabama 25989
13  Alabama 25833
67  Alabama 24484
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need if values are sorted [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) + [`head`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.head.html):

```
df = df.groupby('STNAME').head(3)
```

If not sorted is possible add it by [`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) or use [`nlargest`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.nlargest.html):

```
df = (df.sort_values(['STNAME','CENSUS2010POP'], ascending=[True, False])
        .groupby('STNAME').head(3))
print (df)
         STNAME  CENSUS2010POP
47      Alabama          30776
3       Alabama          27457
31      Alabama          26790
3096  Wisconsin        5686986
3137  Wisconsin         947735
3109  Wisconsin         488073
3169    Wyoming         563626
3180    Wyoming          91738
3182    Wyoming          75450
```

---

```
df = (df.groupby('STNAME')['CENSUS2010POP']
        .nlargest(3)
        .reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
        .reset_index())
print (df)
      STNAME  CENSUS2010POP
0    Alabama          30776
1    Alabama          27457
2    Alabama          26790
3  Wisconsin        5686986
4  Wisconsin         947735
5  Wisconsin         488073
6    Wyoming         563626
7    Wyoming          91738
8    Wyoming          75450
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thank you very much!